# json_decode to associative array whilst preserving datatypes of the keys

Tags: php, json

Given this simple json object:

```
{
  "100": 0,
  "100T": 0
}
```

How do I decode it to an associate array such that both the keys "100" and "100T" remain as strings. When I use json_decode the "100" is converted to an integer.

Example code:

```
$json = '{"100":0, "100T":0}';
$array = json_decode($json, true);
var_dump($array);
```

Gives this output:

```
array(2) {
  [100] =>
  int(0)
  '100T' =>
  int(0)
}
```

But I want this output instead:

```
array(2) {
  '100' =>
  int(0)
  '100T' =>
  int(0)
}
```

I'm using PHP version 7.0.25 on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: PHP arrays internally convert their keys to numbers if possible. This is how they worked since the beginning.

Comment: This article about numeric keys in (associative) arrays in the [PHP 7.2 changelogs](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/convert_numeric_keys_in_object_array_casts) addresses your problem.

Comment: Also [this example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6aec77a00a37b300f67b933122dd9c7350cf1bf6) shows quite good, that numerical string keys in PHP arrays do not exist prior to PHP 7.2, if they are in the Integer range.

Comment: Is there any specific reason you want to this kind of output? You can change the type of value while parsing an array.

Comment: @PhilippMaurer Are you saying I will get a different output if I use PHP 7.2? I don't have 7.2 to hand to test with.

Comment: @David using PHP 7.2.2 I've the same result as yours. The key is an integer.

Comment: So it seems like the only way to get what I want is to convert after decoding. Or convert to an object instead of an array, but this breaks downstream code.

Comment: @David I've read the changelogs posted by Philipp Maurer and there is a link to the commit where this feature is implemented on [Github](https://github.com/php/php-src/commit/a0502b89a65d24eb191a7c85bcffcf9b91454735). It seems this feature is available from PHP 7.2.0. I don't know why I haven't the right result so.

Comment: Maybe the easiest solution is to expect a numeric value in your assertions/comparisons, or to cast `strval()` on each key directly before asserting/comparing it. Since JSON does not know numeric keys and casts all keys to a string you cannot identify if a `json_decode()`'d array key was of type `string` or `integer` once and therefore can not distinguish between both anyway.